# how to input a chunk of html with php

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on a website that uses a login system I made.
I have a div that holds a bar that goes on the top of the website. This bar is supposed to change depending if you're a guest, logged in, or a admin. (Therefor there are three separate divs - guestmode, membermode and adminmode)

I have tried to make php print the html when wanted, and it worked. The only problem is that it's messy and not at all easy to edit.

Is it possible for php to print html without using 'echo' or 'print', but copying from another file?
Basically I want to copy normal html syntaxed-code from a file somewhere and turn it into something that php can print, then of course print it.

Is there something out there that can do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: or jQuery $("#bar").load(whattypeofuser+".html");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP, use something like:

```
echo file_get_contents('path/to/my_html_snippet.my_ext'); // echo instantly
$stored = file_get_contents('path/to/my_html_snippet.my_ext'); // or save it for later in a string
```

Create a file at *path/to/my_html_snippet.my_ext* that contains the HTML you want to print.

Comment: Would it be possible to send that string to javascript, then have a script that can "inject" that html code into a specific div?

Comment: You would have to craft an AJAX request in Javascript to a dedicated PHP script that outputs the string in an XML, HTML, or JSON container (whatever you are most comfortable with). Then your Javascript should be able to parse the response enough to get at the string. If you are getting into AJAX, I recommend using a library like jQuery or YUI, rather than trying to write the transactions from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Its seems like you need a templates.

See mustache (examples and docs - https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php)